# How to show the PI tagsearch dialog and return tagname as string?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

How can I show the PI Tag search dialog, and secondarily, how can I get the selected tag name from it?

Comment: What is "the PI Tag search dialog"?

Comment: @Oded PI is a time-series database/historian. The tag search dialog is commonly invoked from WPF/WinForms applications. I updated the tags to help clarify

Comment: @Michael winforms user control, not wpf

Comment: I may just have some code for that... after dinner though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully this can be of some use to you:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    TagSearch dialog = new TagSearch();

    PointList results = dialog.showTagSearch(
        new string[] { }, SearchOptions.SingleSelect);

    if (results.Count > 0) {
        object index = 1;
        string serverTag = 
            string.Format(
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                @"\\{0}\{1}", 
                results.get_Item(ref index).Server.Name, 
                results.get_Item(ref index).Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! I was close, but this cleans it up and simplifies it.

Answer (score 0):

Please download the PI ProcessBook user manual from the OSIsoft Technical Support website, and see section: PI Tag Search (pg.57):

http://techsupport.osisoft.com/Techsupport/NonTemplates/Download%20Center/DownloadCenter.aspx?download_file=26B66920-EF5F-4ECE-866B-44CD446EED49

Comment: Instead of providing an answer, some code, or examples, you link me to a site I have to create an account to sign into, and refer me to a page in a downloadable user manual? Welcome to stack overflow. Check out this question about good answers [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) on meta.stackoverflow

Comment: @roviuser, it's just the ultimate lfgtfy!

Answer (score 0):

FYI for anyone else looking for similar.

I came here looking for a steer on this, and this code (the accepted answer) was great in pointing me in the right direction.  The syntax has changed slightly in newer versions of the SDK.  Here is my (basic) updated code:

```
public PIPoint SearchForPoint()
    {
        TagSearch searchDialog = new TagSearch();
        PointList result = searchDialog.Show(null, TagSearchOptions.tsoptSingleSelect);
        if (result.Count > 0)
        {
            return result[1];
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This also requires a reference to the PISDKdlg library (mine is version 16.8.0.0).